# Set a tooltip for a hypertext link in a QLabel

Tags: c++, qt5, tooltip, qlabel

I have a QLabel with an embedded link:

```
QString LinkName ("...") ;
QString DestName ("...") ;
QLabel* myLabel ;
...
myLabel -> setText (QString ("Click <a href=\"%1\">here</a> to go to %2")
  .arg (LinkName).arg (DestName))) ;
```

The label is displayed centred in its owner widget.

I want to set a tooltip on the LinkName text, i.e. the clickable text that appears underlined in the QLabel. But I don't know where it is, because I don't know DestName in advance. Is there a way to do this? (I am using Qt5.)

The comments show how to dynamically set a tootip. But how do I know where its rectangle should be? How can I find out the coordinates of the "here" text?

I tried

```
"Click <a href=\"%1\" title=\"Tooltip text\">here</a> to go to %2"
```

but it has no effect.

**Edited to add:** [This Qt Forum entry](https://forum.qt.io/topic/135579/title-attribute-of-html-tag) seems to suggest that what I want is not supported: "The Qt rich text does not include tooltips, unfortunately."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to replicate [HTML title Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) in Qt using a combination of [`QLabel::linkHovered`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlabel.html#linkHovered) and [`QToolTip::showText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtooltip.html#showText) which is `static`.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString LinkName("linkName");
    QString DestName("destName");
    QLabel myLabel;

    myLabel.setText(QString("Click <a href=\"%1\">here</a> to go to %2").arg (LinkName).arg(DestName)) ;

    QObject::connect(&myLabel,&QLabel::linkHovered,[=](const QString &link)
    {
        //link is passed from linkHovered signal as a QString
        //use current cursor position to display the tooltip there
        QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), link);
    });

    myLabel.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image: Link tooltip in a QLabel]